# Angular 10 - DateTime Picker and TimeZone

Tags: angular, datetime

Im having big problem using Angular DateTimePicker and TimeZone.

I have a component to SWITCH at RUNTIME the TimeZone. EVERY date printed in frontent MUST be translated BUT every date sent to Backend MUST BE in UTC.

As you can see, in my app header am printing UTC current Date and YOUR SELECTED date that is different from BROWSER locale (that is current CET +1).

[image]

1. PROBLEM 1

When I open DateTimePicker, the showed date is the current BROWSER LOCALE date (+1). There isn't any parameter to set the TZ. The only way I have found is set TZ to the moment model in FormControl but I don't want to link a TZ to the model I will send to backend.

[image]

2. PROBLEM 2

If im using America/NewYork (-5) and I select 08:00 in datepicker, Im referring to 08:00 in NewYork that is 13:00 for UTC.
So I have to send to backend a timestamp for 13:00 UTC, not 08:00.

Without any way to set TZ to dapicker, What I got is a moment without TZ but if i use .unix() I got an adjusted timestamp considering browser locale (in my case +1).

It really a mess!

[image]

I've tried to user Adapter but they change the way the date is printed (for example DD-MM-YYYY etc...).

How Can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Could you share your code, where you are having the problem. you can use moment utc on the date picker if you want to send to the backend

Comment: But I don't want to show UTC date in DatePicker BUT the current selected TZ (from the dropdown that store TZ info in a cross-component class).

Answer (score 0):

I cant figure out how to solve so I resolved separating property to use in Datetimepicker (that is a moment with tz) and a property with utc_timestamp.

```
utc_from_timestamp      : number = null;
utc_to_timestamp        : number = null;
    
datetime_from           : FormControl    = new FormControl();
datetime_to             : FormControl    = new FormControl();
```

The component refer to datetime_from:

```
<input matInput
           [ngxMatDatetimePicker]  =   "picker_from"
           [formControl]           =   "search_date.datetime_from"
           [min]                   =   "min_date"
           (dateChange)            =   "dateFromChanged()"
            >
```

Then I've created methods to pass from moment to utc_timestamp:
NOTE: AdjustTimestamp is a method that check if timestamp HAS milliseconds.
NOTE: this.timezone.name has something like "America/New_York"

```
 setAbsoluteFrom(utc_from_timestamp)
    {
      this.utc_from_timestamp = UtilityService.adjust_timestamp(utc_from_timestamp);
      var tz_moment = moment(this.utc_from_timestamp);
      this.datetime_from      = new FormControl(tz_moment.tz(this.timezone.name));
    }
```

This method is called after a change in Datetimepicker.
When calling .unix() on a Moment, it returns always am UTC timestamp.

```
 dateFromChanged()
  {
    this.search_date.utc_from_timestamp = this.search_date.datetime_from.value.unix();   
  }
```

I always send utc timestamp to backend and when it return me a utc timestamp, I only need to call setAbsoluteFrom to set internal utc timestamp and component moment.